# Froala WYISWYG editor not showing the toolbar button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, froala

I start with project Froala editor with angular 1 , I follow the documentation step by step , I like to show `insertImage` button and `insertTable` but nothing is showing . this is my code :

```
var tb = [ "bold", "italic" , "insertTable","insertImage" ];
$scope.froalaOptions = {
  toolbarButtons: tb,
  toolbarButtonsMD: tb,
  toolbarButtonsSM: tb,
  toolbarButtonsXS: tb
};
```

And this is my output :

[image]

I have also added the plugins JS&CSS  :

```
<script src="bower_components/froala-wysiwyg-editor/js/plugins/image.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/froala-wysiwyg-editor/js/plugins/table.min.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/froala-wysiwyg-editor/css/plugins/image.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/froala-wysiwyg-editor/css/plugins/table.min.css">
```

but nothing happen . 
Any ideas why?

Comment: do you added the plugins corresponding css as explained in https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/plugins?

Comment: yes I do it but nothing happen !

Comment: did you included the plugins script before your main script? sorry for this silly questions but without viewing your code or a jsfiddle it's hard!

Comment: +1 ... thanks for your answer :D I not included the plugins before my main script ... now everything works :)

Answer (score 1):

The following plugins needs to be imported to use table and image  with toolbar buttons in app.module.ts.

1) import 'froala-editor/js/plugins.pkgd.min.js'

2) You have to import plugin to use image "image.min.ts" 
or 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/3.0.6/js/plugins/image.min.js in a file.